# How to add SWidgetSwitcher and get/set current widget index in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, menu, unreal-engine4, slate

I'm trying to make a simple menu widget with Slate. I'm able to add canvas, buttons etc like `SNew(SCanvas)` but I am stuck with `SNew(SWidgetSwitcher)`, on
how to use this and set the widget index. I'm new to this and havn't found much info on Google, so:
How to I add an `SWidgetSwitcher` and get/set *current widget index* in *Unreal Engine 4*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SNew(SWidgetSwitcher)
.WidgetIndex(this, &SMyUIWidget::GetCurrentTabIndex)
```

This might help you: https://nerivec.github.io/old-ue4-wiki/pages/slate-tabs.html

Comment: You can mark it as the answer if it has helped to help others find it as well.